# Automatically detecting and outputing to s-video at startup

Tags: boot, scripts, monitor

After combing the Internet I have developed a script that is capable of checking whether I have a monitor connected to my VGA port and switching to my s-video port if not

```
#!/bin/bash
# if no vga then Enable S-Video at 800x600
if [$(xrandr -q| grep "VGA-0 disconnected") == ""]
then
# vga is connected do nothing   
else
# no vga switch to s-video
    xrandr
    xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600
    xrandr --output S-video --set "tv standard" ntsc
    xrandr --output S-video --set "load detection" 1
    xrandr --output S-video --right-of VGA-0 --mode 800x600
    sleep 10
    xrandr
fi
```

now how do I set it up to run at the correct time when I boot the computer so that it will pick my tv when there is no monitor connected.